# joining rows with columns mysql

Tags: mysql

i have two tables where i need to select data from

**user**

```
id   email
----------
1   email1
2   email2
```

**settings**

```
usrid name    value
--------------------
1    set1     value1
1    set2     value2
2    set1     value1
2    set2     value2
```

and the sql i used is

```
SELECT u.email, s . * 
FROM `sers` u
INNER JOIN `settings` s ON u.id = s.usrid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but i get

```
email  name value
------------------
email1  set1  value1
email1  set1  value1
email2  set2  value2
email2  set2  value1
```

is there any way to get

```
email1  set1 value1 set1 value1 etc
email2  set2 value2 set2 value2 etc
```

from the group_concat i tried this

```
SELECT u.email, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name,s.value) as vals FROM `users` u INNER JOIN `settings` s ON u.id = s.usrid GROUP BY u.email
```

which gave

```
email1  set1value1,set1value1 etc
```

how can i make put a separator between each values between the comma

like

```
email1  set1=value1,set1=value1 etc
```

Comment: do they only have maximum of 2 settings?

Comment: Join works if both columns are identical.

Comment: @491243 no, there are about 7 for each user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/782e3/6

```
SELECT u.email, CONCAT_WS(',', GROUP_CONCAT( s.name),
                 GROUP_CONCAT( s.value)) AS allValues
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN `settings` s ON u.id = s.usrid GROUP BY email
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP  BY`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.email,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.name,'='  ,s.value SEPARATOR ',')
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN `settings` s ON u.id = s.usrid
GROUP BY u.email;
```